# which is the appropriate place to call poll function in javascript code in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an ajax request which saves some percentage completion data in db.for polling purpose i have written one more function which gives me real time update from that same table.

All i want is to poll my db when actual ajax request responsible for saving is still in process.
here is the code i am using.you can see that i am calling setTimeout(letsPoll, interval) at the success of it which is quite late because it will get called when whole request will be completed and ofcourse then it will 100% which is of no use as my progress bar then show 100% completion directly. My only question is where to call this line

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var interval = 2000;
  $(document).on('click', '#submit-catalog', function() {
    $('#submit-catalog').prop("disabled", true);
    var url = [[@{'/admin/catalog/activate'}]];
    var xhr = $.ajax({
      url: url,
      success: function(data) {
        setTimeout(letsPoll, interval);
      },
      complete: function(data) {
      }
    });
  });

  function letsPoll() {
    $('#progress-bar').show();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: [[@{'/admin/catalog/getPercentageCompletion'}]],
      success: function(data) {
        $('.progress-text').text(data + '%');
        $('#upload-progress').css('width', data + '%');
        if (data == 100) {
          clearTimeout(interval);
          aqShowInfoToast("All hosted catalogs has been Activated");
          $('#submit-catalog').prop("disabled", false);
          aqCloseModal();
        }
      },
      complete: function(data) {
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Create the timeout *before* you make the initial request. Also note that AJAX polling is not an ideal solution. You may want to look in to WebSockets or Server Sent Events.

Comment: is there any work around if don't want to use websocket/SSE ? i cant create poll before initial request becaue my initial request is the one which is saving percentage in table. also that initial request happens when one click submit catalog button. if one is not clicking that then i dont want my poll to happen either.

Comment: There's no other alternatives to communicate with the server without reloading the page. You misunderstood what I meant. I mean that you need to place the `setTimeout()` just before the `$.ajax()` call in the click handler